# which mobile platforms supports SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, mobile

As i am being an Android developer, and android is supporting SQLite database,

i would like to know that which are the other mobile platforms supports the SQLite Database
so that i can make SQLite database common and can place it at one place,
and thereafter i can make database transaction from different mobile platforms.

Comment: [iPhone](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/tutorial-discussion/4086-my-iphone-sqlite-tutorial.html),
[s60](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlites60/),
[windows CE](http://sqlite-wince.sourceforge.net/),
[windows mobile](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) What else do you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Due to its small size, SQLite is well suited to embedded systems, and is also included in Apple's iOS (where it is used for the SMS/MMS, Calendar, Call history and Contacts storage), Symbian OS, Google's Android, RIM's BlackBerry and Palm's webOS.[20] However, it is also suitable for desktop operating systems; Apple adopted it as an option in Mac OS X's Core Data API from the original implementation in Mac OS X 10.4 onwards."

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite#Adoption

Comment: So 'every' Android device - be it 'smartophones' or 'tablets' - support sqllite as a storage option?

Answer (score 2):

If I am not wrong, even meego and maemo have support for sql lite database... In-fact sql lite was created for hand held devices, it doesn't provide all the functionalities of full fledged SQL but then you need to consider its being run on a battery powered device!

Comment: http://meego.com/ Its the platform used by the N900 nokia phones... they are based on moblin(mobile linux).